# Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem doesn't change IsEnabled from XAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I'm facing a problem with `ToolbarItem` and `IsEnabled` property when trying to turn it on/off from XAML using triggers. `ToolbarItem` doesn't support triggers, so what I do is to create a `Button` (a hidden one) which supports triggers and then bind `Button.IsEnabled` to `ToolbarItem.IsEnabled`; here is the sample code:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="tlbSave" Text="Save" Clicked="Handle_Clicked">
            <ToolbarItem.IsEnabled>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference btnTest}" Path="IsEnabled" />
            </ToolbarItem.IsEnabled>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Padding="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <Entry x:Name="txtTest" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Text="HIDDEN" IsEnabled="false" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtTest}, Path=Text.Length,
                                                           Converter={convert:IsPositiveIntegerConverter}}" Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

If you try this piece of code you will see how `btnTest` gets enable/disable when `txtTest.Text` has some value. But it isn't affecting `tlbSave.IsEnabled` property.

However, this work perfect in code behind when I set `tlbSave.IsEnabled` into `btnText.PropertyChanged` **EventHandler**

`btnTest.IsVisible` is **false**, I'm just showing it up for testing purposes.

Any idea about how to deal with this?

Comment: Why exactly are you using triggers? Curiosity! Also shouldn't your binding look something like `<ToolbarItem IsEnabled={Binding IsEnabled, Source="{x:Reference btnTest}}" />`

Comment: It's the same, just another way to do it

Comment: Hi. I am having the same issue. Replaced all my buttons with ToolbarItems and see the same behavior. When you have a hidden button binding to the same property it works. I set the IsEnabled property in the ValidateSave command/event to enable the save button/ToolbarItem but without the hidden button the Validate save commans/event wont fire. Any Idea?

Answer (score 8):

This is because of the IsEnabled property of ToolbarItem is **read-only**.

If you just set IsEnabled property of a toolbar item in your XAML to false or true, you will get the following exception at runtime.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The BindableProperty "IsEnabled" is readonly.
```

And if you take a look at [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.menuitem.isenabled?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_MenuItem_IsEnabled), you will notice that you cannot directly set IsEnabled property of a toolbar item.

For disabling a toolbar item, the suggested way is to use a command and it's CanExecute.

Comment: In XAML we can't assign a boolean value to `IsEnabled` because it's a bindable property. However in code behind I can change its value.

Comment: "For disabling a toolbar item," does that work for you? I've seen bug reports from 2015 saying it doesn't disable based on CanExecute and still executes. I am on XF 4.4 and the CanExecute does not seem to be be respected even now

Comment: From where do you see it's read only? There is a getter and a setter. The only notice I can see is *For internal use by the Xamarin.Forms platform.*

Answer (score 2):

I found out a way to solve this problem, at least a way better than implementing `OnPropertyChange` for `btnTest`

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="tlbSave" Text="Save" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Padding="10" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

            <Entry x:Name="txtTest" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Text="HIDDEN">
                <Button.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference txtTest}, Path=Text.Length,
                                                           Converter={convert:IsPositiveIntegerConverter}}" Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Button.Triggers>

                <Button.IsEnabled>
                    <Binding Source="{x:Reference tlbSave}" Path="IsEnabled" Mode="OneWayToSource" />
                </Button.IsEnabled>
            </Button>

        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Then set `btnTest.IsEnabled = false;` inside constructor and everything will go as smooth as I want.